# (octave-mode) highlighted region remains highlighted after command

Tags: region, octave

I am in octave-mode running an inferior octave shell. Now I mark a region and issue 'octave-send-region'. All commands are executed as expected and echoed in the shell buffer, and the highlighting is cleared.

So far so good, this is how it is supposed to work and how it does work **initially**. After a couple of more region-sending, however, the corresponding commands are still executed, but the **highlighting fails to clear** (it can be cleared using Ctrl-g).

I see this behavior now for at least a couple of years, and it is quite annoying. Before it was ok.

Anyone know about this behavior, and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this happen only with Octave? Does it happen even if you start Emacs with `emacs -Q` (no init file)? If so, maybe report this as a bug to the Octave maintainer, if you don't get a helpful answer here.

Comment: I just tried with shell-mode and matlab-mode, and I see the same behavior. I am on Linux Manjaro with octave, emacs,... being quite recent.

Comment: I suggest `M-x report-emacs-bug RET`

Comment: ...and that was with -Q. For matlab and shell mode, highlighting was never cleared. For octave-mode, it did clear for a number of times, until I commented out some portion in the region (which may or may not be important) when it again failed to clear.

Comment: It appears as if a similar behaviour can be observed when using `C-c C-i b` for executing a block. Can anybody confirm this? I was not able to spot the cause.

Comment: Yes, and likewise for the corresponding command for functions `C-c C-i f`. I am happy that there is at least one more user out there to see this behavior!